# Comparing the etymologies of the adjective and participle 'latus'

Tags: etymology, word-comparison, adjective, participle

What are the etymologies of the adjective *latus* ("wide") and the participle *latus* ("carried")?
I had assumed that they are the same and the participle just started a new life as an adjective after a semantic shift.
However, fdb commented on [my earlier question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/6358/79) and told that these two words are etymologically distinct.
So, what are these etymologies and what evidence has lead to accepting that they are distinct?

(I will leave the noun *latus* to the side, as it seems to be unrelated to these two with a long *a*.)

Comment: have you looked at: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/latus#Latin ?  They seem to be making a distinction between *stlātus/*stelh₃- and *tlātus (from Proto-Italic *tlātos) from the PIE  *tl̥h₂tós, from the root *telh₂-

Comment: *telh₂ makes me think of "hill", but the roots for "tel" [תֵּל‎](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%9C#Hebrew),  [تَلّ‎](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%AA%D9%84#Arabic) indicate Proto-Semitic *tall- (“hill”), and I haven't yet run down [*telh₂](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/telh%E2%82%82-) in any of the alternate online PIE dictionaries...

Comment: @DukeZhou I took a look at that, but the lack of citations in Wiktionary is a little disturbing. There is a list of references at the end, but I don't know where the PIE roots were pulled from. With some digging the Wiktionary article could be turned into a nice answer. It would also be nice to see a more explicit comparison: why do we think the two words are distinct if there are no distinct attested predecessors in Latin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Latin **lātus** 'having been carried' (originally from tollo, already in Old Latin a suppletive participle form of fero) < PIt. ***tlātos** > PIE ***tl̩h<sub>2</sub>tós**, an adjective from the PIE verb ***telh<sub>2</sub>-** (aorist), since the reconstructed present form is *tl̩-neh<sub>2</sub>- (LIV).

The sound changes/correspondences are well-known: PIE lH > Latin lā; zero-grade.

Latin **lātus** 'broad' > PIt. ***slātos** > PIE ***stl̩h<sub>x</sub>tós**, an adjective from the PIE verb ***stel(h<sub>x</sub>)-** 'spread' (at least, according to Weiss 2009/2011: 292), the more usual notation is PIE ***stl̩Htós**. The sound change is also known, cf. "*stl*- is retained into the OL period but is normally simplified to just *l*-" (Weiss 2009/2011: 177), cf. locus < stlocus.

However, de Vaan adopts the LIV reconstruction of that root, *stel-, i.e. without the laryngeal, which would make this etymological connection problematic.

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer while I search for a copy of De Vaan…

These two words were distinct in Old Latin. The word for "wide" was originally *stlātus*, while "borne" was *tlātus*.

*Stlātus*, according to Lewis and Short, is connected to Sanskrit *strnāmi*, Greek *stórnymi* and *stratós*, Latin *sternō* and *stratus*, and English *strew*. The *st-* is still visible in the archaic word *stlāt(t)a*, "barge". All of these come from PIE **sterh₃-* "extend, stretch". Unfortunately, L&S don't specify how the **r* turned into *l*, but *d* turning into *l* is well-attested (see *lacrima*, *lingua*), and this might be a similar process?

*Tlātus*, on the other hand, was originally the fourth principal part of *tollō*, *tollere*, *tulī*, *tlātus*, cognate with Greek *tlētos* "steadfast". (In Classical times the third and fourth parts were stolen by the unrelated verb *ferō*, so *tollō* needed to add prefixes to keep them distinct.) This verb came from the PIE root **telh₂* "bear". The varying vowels go back to the patterns of PIE ablaut: *tlātus* in particular is from the zero-grade **tlh₂*, with the laryngeal turning into the *ā*, while the other parts come from a full grade. The present stem gets its extra *l* from a nasal infix that assimilated.

Both of these words then got simplified when Latin stopped allowing the combination *tl*, and ended up looking the same by pure coincidence. As Alex B points out in his own answer, this is a known sound change: *locus* comes from *stlocus*.

Comment: "These two words were distinct in Old Latin." Most likely it was so, but still this is not a fact since there is no textual/epigraphic evidence.

Comment: @AlexB. L&S cite "Paul. ex Fest. p. 313" for Old Latin *stlātus*, and the cognate *stlāt(t)a* is attested in a few places. Unfortunately I haven't found any evidence cited for *tlātus* except comparison with the other principal parts and the Greek cognate (nothing in other Italic languages even).

Comment: Hannah Rosén (Rosén 1988) writes that "Stlat(t)a  itself is attested, evidently referring to a vessel of some kind or another, in various sources **from the second century A.D. onwards**"  (p. 117; emphasis mine - Alex B.), CIL VIII 27790 (dubia) is the 3rd century AD.  Festus most likely lived in the second century AD as well, a period that can be hardly called Old Latin.

Comment: @AlexB. Ah! Very interesting; I wonder why these forms appeared so late? (Probably deserves its own question.)

Comment: @Draconis Did this question ever get asked? I'd also like to know the story behind this.

Comment: @cmw I can't find it in my question history, so I probably forgot to ask. Feel free to ask it now, or I can look into it later tonight.