# How can participles (inflected forms) be distinguished from deverbal adjectives (derived forms) in Latin?

Tags: syntax, adjective, derivation, conjugation, participle

Many modern linguistic analyses of languages like English draw a sharp theoretical distinction between **participles**, which are analyzed as inflected forms belonging to the paradigm of some verb, and **deverbal adjectives** (also called verbal adjectives, participial adjectives, or departicipial adjectives), which are seen as adjectives derived from verbs. (There are certainly disputes about the validity of the inflection/derivation  dichotomy, but it nevertheless seems to have wide acceptance. There are also disputes about whether participles should be analyzed as verbs, adjectives, neither or both, but I don't think that's as relevant to my question. Also, the word "participle" is often used in a broad sense that covers both an inflected form and a derived word with an identical form, but the broad vs. narrow definitions of "participle" just seem to be a matter of terminology.)

However, it can be tricky to determine which category a word belongs to in a specific example sentence. There are some syntactic tests, but often they only work in particular situations and can only give a definite answer in one direction. (E.g., in English, if an *-ing* word has a direct object, that is considered to be proof that it is a participle and not a deverbal adjective, but if it doesn't have a direct object, it might be either a participle or a deverbal adjective. If an *-ing* word is modified by the word *very,* that is considered to be proof that it is a deverbal adjective and not a participle, but if it is not or cannot be modified by the word *very,* it might be either a participle or a deverbal adjective.)

I would like to know about any such syntactic tests that have been noted or proposed for distinguishing Latin participles (in the sense of "inflected forms") from derived adjectives.

Comment: May I ask if you found some criteria to make this distinction in the end?

Answer (score 6):

Since posting this question, I have found some information, although I'm not as sure of it as I would like to be. I use some hedging in this answer, but this is only meant to indicate my personal lack of certainty; I'm not saying that the matter is objectively uncertain.

### Possible syntactic differences

#### *-ns* words may only take accusative direct objects when they are participles

Apparently, in Latin, as in English, a verbal active participle can take a direct object in the accusative case, but a departicipial adjective typically can't. I asked a separate question about this topic: [When are -ns words used with accusative direct objects?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/9130/when-are-ns-words-used-with-accusative-direct-objects)

#### Adjectives, but not participles, can take comparative morphology

Joonas Ilmavirta asked a question about
[Comparison of participles](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/6358/comparison-of-participles). Based on the current answers, it seems that the use of comparative or superlative morphology is typically viewed as a sign that a word is a departicipial adjective rather than a true verbal participle.

### Possible morphological differences

#### negation with *non* for participles vs. negation with *in-* for adjectives

The following information doesn't help much to distinguish participles from adjectives when a word is not negated, but it seems relevant to the overall question of whether Latin distinguished verbal and adjectival participles:

> in Classical Latin the synchronic negative of e.g. *patiens* ‘enduring’
> is *non patiens*, whereas participles with a negative prefix are synchronically non-participial adjectives, e.g. *impatiens* ‘impatient’.

(p. 30, "[Negated Participles in Ṛgvedic Sanskrit and Proto-Indo-European](http://users.ox.ac.uk/%7Eshug1472/IIJ_054_01_1075-Lowe_print-1.pdf)," by John J. Lowe, *Indo-Iranian Journal* 54 (2011) 19-38)

#### *-ns* participles and adjectives might inflect differently in the ablative

Bennett's *[Latin Grammar](https://books.google.com/books?id=pQD1AQAAQBAJ&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=%22vetera%22#v=onepage&q=%22vetera%22&f=false)* says

> Participles in *-ans* and *-ens* follow the declension of **ĭ**-stems. But they do not have **-ī** in the Ablative, except when employed as adjectives; when used as participles or as substantives, they have **-e**; as--
>
> > **ā sapientī virō,** *by a wise man ;* but
> >
> >  **ā sapiente,** *by a philosopher*
> >
> >  **Tarquiniō rēgnante,** *under the reign of Tarquin*

("Adjectives of the Third Declension", §70 "Adjectives of One Termination")

However, it seems that this is at best a simplification, at worst a misrepresentation of the usage of these two forms. In "[Declension of the Latin present participle in connection with its syntactico-semantic use](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/joll-2018-0001/html)" (2018), Hendrik Christiaan Walvoort says "I conclude that a twofold declension paradigm of the ppa according to syntactico-semantic use is only mentioned in the sixth/seventh century by the anonymous author of the *Ars Ambrosiana,* but not by the ancient and the other medieval grammarians" (§3). Even if it is a real rule, there are apparently many exceptions, so inflection is not a reliable way of distinguishing verbal participles from adjectives.