# Auster misceat mare aestum

Tags: poetry

This is from Boethius Consolation of Philosophy, which can be found here:

http://mizar.unive.it/mqdq/public/testo/testo?codice=BOETH%7Ccons%7C001

Si mare uoluens
Turbidus Auster
Misceat aestum,

And is translated here:

http://thelatinreadingblog.blogspot.com/search/label/boethius

I'm having trouble with 'aestum'.  If the above sentence means: If the turbulent South Wind stirs the rolling sea into a passion, where 'aestum' means passion, then I'm having trouble with case of 'aestum'.  If it is accusative then we have two accusative nouns: 'mare' and 'aestum' which doesn't make sense to me. Further, if 'aestum' is accusative then that would ruin the meter since the meter is

. - u u | - -  (the dot is necessary since stackexchange uses - as a coding element)

And that line would break the meter with:

. - u u | - u

It could also be that 'aestum' is a plural genetive but then it would have to be spelled 'aestuum'.  However, some people believe that double vowels were pronounced as one long vowel (I can track down a link if you really want me to) and maybe in the 5th century things had departed a bit from classical Latin and 4th declension plural genitives were written  with one final 'u'.  A third solution is that I think sometimes the final element of a poetic line is not all that important because a short vowel can be compensated with a silent pause so as to not destroy the rhythm.  Let me know if there is a 4th solution.

Answer (score 5):

#### Syntax

"mare" and "aestum" are both accusative: "mare" is the accusative object of the participle "volvens", while "aestum" is the accusative object of the finite verb "misceat".

"Volvens" here is a verbal participle meaning something like "-rolling", as in "The sea-rolling South Wind" (with the sense "the South Wind, which makes the sea roll"). [Present participles in Latin can be used verbally or adjectivally](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/6462); when used verbally, [a present participle can take an accusative direct object](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/9130), the same as a finite verb. (They can also take other kinds of complements that finite verbs can take.) [Allen and Greenough's *Latin Grammar*](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/tense-participles) describes this by saying that the participle "may govern a case" and "often takes an object" (§488).

There is an example of the use of *volvens* used predicatively with the accusative direct object *hostilia cadavera* in [§496](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/uses-participles):

> Volventēs hostīlia cadāvera amīcum reperiēbant. (Sall. Cat. 61)
>
> While rolling over the corpses of the enemy they found a friend. [Time]

Based on my reading of dictionary entries, it appears *[volvo](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/volvo)* is more often transitive than intransitive.

#### Scansion

For the scansion, it is a general rule of Latin poetry that any syllable can be used as the final syllable of a line, regardless of its lexically specified weight/length. One way of interpreting that is that any line-final syllable counts as long. It's therefore not possible for a line to break the meter by ending in - u.

Comment: Well, if by object of a participle you mean that which is modified by a participle then the translation 'rolling sea' agrees with that assertion.  You haven't stated whether or not you think that both 'mare' and 'aestum' are both accusative and if they are how do we translate that into English?  I'm vaguely aware of a double accusative construction from the Greenough grammar but I think it is only used for making assertions of identity.

Comment: @bobsmith76 *Mare* and *aestum* are both accusative.

Comment: I don't think this a case of double accusative, because there are two different verbs.  "Mare" would be the direct object of "volvens" and "aestum" would be the direct object of "misceat."

Comment: @Asteroides, thank you for your help.  Can you point me to the section in the Greenough grammar, if there is one, which discusses participles having accusative objects.  I remember that on some occasions the gerundives which are adjectives can sometimes cause nouns to be in the accusative case but I do not recall that happens for words in the present participle?  Thank you.

Comment: This is a tough issue and one that requires a few examples.

Comment: thanks i appreciate that.